# How to create Facebook action links on FB posts/comments?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a web based feed application, which aggregates user's feed with posts and comments. I need to provide share, comment and like links for already existing facebook objects.

Graph API provides **actions** with some posts, like "like" or "comment". They are passed as an array, and contains action name, and a link - but the link opens dedicated fb post page - and both are the same. E.g. they open the post page, but not perform the action mentioned.

I believe it is possible to create the action link itself for each separate action, otherwise there are no sense in passing actions information, but couldn't find a method in API or SDK docs.

PHP sdk v3 used, but any suggestions or examples would help.

Comment: _“E.g. they open the post page, but not perform the action mentioned”_ – they don’t, because they are the internal “default” actions every such post has, and can be performed by the user via the UI that is already present when visiting the link. […]

Comment: […] If you want to use your own action link, you have to point it to an address belonging to your app, and then that URL gets hit by Facebook when the user clicks on the link. The details are described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.1#howto-actionlinks – that description is specifically tailored for use with OG actions; if you want to do the same thing for normal posts, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed/#publish